# Numpy .dot() ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to understand the broblem. My input matrix is (60,4) and my weight matrix is (4, 2). The multiplication can easily be done (from the mathematical point of view, the final matrice is (60,2)). But the Numpy shows an error that I couldn't explain.

```
self.output = np.dot (inputs, self.weights) + self.biases
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (60,4) (4,2)
```

Comment: `np.dot` doesn't raise `broadcasting` errors.  I think it's the `+` that's having problem.  Tell us the shape of all 3 arrays.  Or test each part separately.

Comment: `dot` produces errors like `ValueError: shapes (4,2) and (4,4) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your inputs are matrices rather than vectors. One way to do it is:

```py
np.matrix(a) * np.matrix(b)
```

But you don't actually have to. There are many alternatives that achieve the same result:

```py
np.tensordot(a, b, 1)
```

Another way:

```py
np.einsum('ij,jh', a, b)
```

Yet another:

```py
np.matmul(a, b)
```

And the winner:

```py
a @ b
```

Comment: `np.dot` is the dot product.  That's not the same thing as matrix multiply.

Comment: We don't recommend using `np.matrix` anymore.  Read the docs.

Comment: I feel it should be there for completeness and to emphasise that there is no reason why arbitrary tensors should be treated as matrices by a multiplication operator unless it's `matmul`

Comment: All over those are the same as `np.dot(a,b)` for 2d arrays.  The OP's error was not produced by the `np.dot` call.

Comment: I agree something is off here but biases should not have a shape of (4,2) and OP claims the two matrices are "inputs" and "weights"